# vCenter Server Appliance - Additional users

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter

Is it possible to add other users to access the VCSA interface ONLY `https://ipaddress:5480` without AD or SSO configuration?

I can see a number of tutorials on adding users via shell access but yet I can not get in to the VCSA web GUI after.  I also found this -

http://blogs.vmware.com/vsphere/2013/09/virtual-appliances-getting-more-secure-with-vsphere-5-5-part-3.html

However same issue, I can create a user with SSH access but I can't get to the web interface.

Comment: Why do you want this? In normal usage, NOBODY should need to access the VCSA configuration page other than the *root* user. Can you provide more context on what you're doing?

Comment: Company wants a way to separate users as this interfaces houses the update and upgrade and reboot features etc...  This is for logging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

> Company wants a way to separate users as this interfaces houses the
>   update and upgrade and reboot features etc... This is for logging
>   purposes.

That doesn't make sense. Restrict access to the VCSA management interface or establish a policy around the use of its password. The vCenter Server Appliance was not meant to be used in a multiuser fashion. If you need more granular permissions, open a support ticket with VMware. They will likely say the same think about its usage, though...